# Change webdev serve directory

Tags: dart, dart2js, dart-build

prentend that I have a file in `.../web/main.dart` and when I'm serving the app ( `webdev serve web:8080`) it will be located in `localhost:8080/main.dart.js` and the packages in `localhost:8080/packages/` is there anyway to move them to `localhost:8080/foo/main.dart` and `localhost/foo/packages/` ?
Basically add `/foo/` to all `dartdevc` generated dictories.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not supported by the default dev server (and is unlikely ever to be).

The typical way to do this would be to set up a separate server, which delegates all things under the `/foo` route to the dev server, and strips out `/foo` from the path.